# How to embed a chart in email when sending out to using mandrill

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, charts

I want to give out weekly report as a email to the merchant based on certain data where I want to include the chart. Generally on a website I'm using chartkick to draw the charts, but how do I embed chart in an email. Please help me out.

My model code

```
def weekly_emailer
  # Some code here
  visits = Visit.group(:created_at).count
end
```

My view code

```
<%= line_chart @visits %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using Highcharts they have a way of converting the chart to a PNG file (and I think a couple of other options).

However in order to have that work you have two options:

1. Send the data and chart configuration to their server for conversion
2. Download a server implementation for it, though only available for a few languages

I've sent a few charts for them for conversion for non-sensitive data, in the past, and that worked pretty well :) Though its worth noting that all of this was a few years ago..

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I'm Image-Charts founder*.

As a indiehacker, I had the same question as you each time I started a new SaaS I had to rewrite from scratch an image generation backend and then send these charts through emails... :(

That's why I've built **[Image-charts](https://image-charts.com)**  and added [gif animation](https://image-charts.com/documentation#chart-gif-animation) on top of it (chart animations in emails are awesome!!), no more server-side chart rendering pain, no scaling issues, it's blazing fast, 1 URL = 1 image chart.

```
https://image-charts.com/chart
?cht=bvg
&chd=t:10,15,25,30,40,80
&chs=700x300
&chxt=x,y
&chxl=0:|March '18|April '18|May '18|June '18|July '18|August '18|
&chdl=Visitors (in thousands)
&chf=b0,lg,90,05B142,1,0CE858,0.2
&chxs=1N**K
&chtt=Visitors report
&chma=0,0,10,10
&chl=||||+33% !|x2 !
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because Chartkick generates charts using [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org), You can take the Chart.js config object generated by Chartkick and render it using [QuickChart](https://quickchart.io), an open-source image renderer for Chart.js charts: https://github.com/typpo/quickchart.

Unlike the other answers on this post, this actually works for Chartkick-generated charts.

Take a Chart.js config like this one.  This is similar to the config that Chartkick generates:

```
{
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Data',
      data: [12, 6, 5, 18, 12]
    }]
  }
}
```

Pack it into the URL like so (you can also self-host this because it's open source):

[https://quickchart.io/chart?bkg=white&c={ type: 'bar', data: { labels: [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016], datasets: [{ label: 'Data', data: [12, 6, 5, 18, 12] }] }}](https://quickchart.io/chart?bkg=white&c=%7B%0A%20%20type%3A%20'bar'%2C%0A%20%20data%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20labels%3A%20[2012%2C%202013%2C%202014%2C%202015%2C%202016]%2C%0A%20%20%20%20datasets%3A%20[%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20'Data'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20[12%2C%206%2C%205%2C%2018%2C%2012]%0A%20%20%20%20%7D]%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Then include the image in your email (for more complex charts it's usually best to url encode the config):

```
<img src="https://quickchart.io/chart?bkg=white&c={type:'bar',data:{labels:[2012,2013,2014,2015,2016],datasets:[{label:'Data',data:[12,6,5,18,12]}]}}" />
```

This image will appear in your email:

[image: Quickchart chart image]

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this with chartkick (yet), but we just released this last week: https://ChartURL.com :)

You can generate charts on the fly using an "Encrypted URL" scheme, or you can send us huge amounts of data and return a Short URL that'll resolve to an image.

It was built on top of http://C3js.org so there's a ton of flexibility in what you can generate.

These URLs can be used in web apps & mobile apps, but the original intent was email charts.

We're going to be working on a chartkick pull request that brings in ChartURL, but in the meantime, I hope this can be helpful!